# Import libraries sbt in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

If I create a sbt project from intelliJ, the sbt-and-plugins libraries are added in external libraries:

[image: project with library sbt-and-plugins]

If I open a folder with scale code from IntelliJ, there is no sbt-and-plugins library in external libraries. Because? How can I add it?

[image: project without library sbt-and-plugins]

Comment: `If I open a folder with scale code` - what do you mean?

Comment: In SBT-based projects IDE configures [dependencies for modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html), based on SBT configuration which it takes from build.sbt file. So sbt-and-plugins library is added in this case for corresponding scala library.

Comment: There's a setting for the sbt plugin (per project) where you can tell IntelliJ to also download the sbt-plugin sources. Maybe that's the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with this link [Module Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html).

I added that library by going to file-> Project structure-> Modules | Dependencies and I entered the library by clicking on library